# Regular Expression Strict Test

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create regex where user have to enter exactly the same thing no extra no less

Here is my regex;
`/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.myshopify\.com/`

when I test this with, for example, `myshop.myshopify.coma` it returns true or `myshop.myshopify.com myshop123.myshopify.com` still returns true

What I am trying to get is if user enters `myshop.myshopify.coma` or `myshop321.myshopify.com myshop123.myshopify.coma` it shouldn't be match.

It should only match when the entire input is exactly like this [anything except ()=>%$ etc].myshopify.com

what should I include in my regex to strictly test exactly one thing.

Comment: use `^` and `$`

Comment: thanks for the reply. Where should I be using them?

Comment: `^` at the start of your pattern and `$` at the end. i.e `/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.myshopify\.com$/`

Comment: check this to understand more: [Regex Assertions MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions)

Comment: ```[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.myshopify\.com ``` this seems correct to me, check here : https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: @Shail_bee thank you for the reply. You can check Tibebes. M's answer that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [boundary-type assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions) to match the beginning of an input (`^`) and an end (`$`) - to make sure your input matches fully.

```js
const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.myshopify\.com$/

console.log(pattern.test('myshop.myshopify.com')) // true
console.log(pattern.test('myshop.myshopify.coma')) // false
console.log(pattern.test('myshop.myshopify.com myshop123.myshopify.com')) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd currently allow for input like "A---", so besides the good point about start and end line anchors, you'd maybe want to reconsider your pattern. Maybe something like:

```
^[a-z\d]+(?:-[a-z\d]+)*\.myshopify\.com$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/72Jchl/5)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `[a-z\d]+` - 1+ any alnum character.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `-[a-z\d]+` - A literal hyphen followed by 1+ alnum chars.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match it zero or more times.
- `\.myshopify\.com` - Match a ".myshopify.com" literallyy.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

A 2nd option would be to use a negative lookahead to achieve the same concept:

```
^(?!-|.*-[-.])[a-z\d-]+\.myshopify\.com$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/72Jchl/4)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?!` - Negative lookahead for:

  - `-` - A leading hypen
  - `|` - Or:
  - `.*-[-.]` - Any character other than newline zero or more times up to an hypen with either another hypen or a literal dot.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - 1+ any alnum character.
- `\.myshopify\.com` - Match a ".myshopify.com" literallyy.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

In both cases I used both the global and case-insensitive flags: `/<pattern>/gi`. See a sample below:

```js
const patt1 = /^[a-z\d]+(?:-[a-z\d]+)*\.myshopify\.com$/gi
console.log(patt1.test('myshop.myshopify.com'))
console.log(patt1.test('myshop-.myshopify.com'))

const patt2 = /^(?!-|.*-[-.])[a-z\d-]+\.myshopify\.com$/gi
console.log(patt2.test('myshop.myshopify.com'))
console.log(patt2.test('myshop-.myshopify.com'))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have looked at yours and tried it myself it is actually much better but user can have `a----b----b----c.myshopify.com` or `zubido35----.myshopify.com` I know it's weird but it is still a optional answer but not for this specific question

Comment: @AhmetK, well those indeed are strange looking valid inputs. Either way. You have your answer =).